# Why doesn't the web driver close after the first test when the test is run with the parameterized decorator?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest

This problem is about the first test with different parameter. It works, but it doesn't shut down properly. Because of this, the second test with different parameter cannot start.

Here is the conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def driver(request):
    driver = BrowserFactory.create_chrome_driver()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com")

    def teardown():
        driver.quit()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)

    return driver

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def inventory_object(driver):
    # Create an instance of the Dummy class
    return Inventory(driver)


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def login_test_data():
    df = pandas.read_csv(r"C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/Testdata/login.csv")
    dicts = df.to_dict('records')
    return dicts

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def login_object(driver):
    return LoginPage(driver)
```

Here is the test_inventory.py

```
 @pytest.mark.parametrize("values", ["za","hilo","liho"])
    def test_select_za(self,values,login_test_data,login_object,inventory_object):
        self.test_login.test_login_successful(login_test_data, login_object)
        print(values)
        inventory_object.select_filter(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), a pytest plugin for Selenium testing.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, you can run a script like this with `pytest`: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_pytest_parametrize.py (which uses `@pytest.mark.parametrize()`)

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "value", ["List of Features", "Command Line Options"]
)
def test_sb_fixture_with_no_class(sb, value):
    sb.open("seleniumbase.github.io/help_docs/install/")
    sb.type('input[aria-label="Search"]', value)
    sb.click("nav h1 mark")
    sb.assert_title_contains(value)
    sb.assert_text(value, "div.md-content")


class Test_SB_Fixture:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "value", ["Console Scripts", "API Reference"]
    )
    def test_sb_fixture_inside_class(self, sb, value):
        sb.open("seleniumbase.github.io/help_docs/install/")
        sb.type('input[aria-label="Search"]', value)
        sb.click("nav h1 mark")
        sb.assert_title_contains(value)
        sb.assert_text(value, "div.md-content")
```

There are lots of advanced command-line options that you can add, such as `--rs`, which makes all tests reuse the same browser session (`pytest --rs`).